# setOnItemClickListener VS setOnItemSelectedListener in ListView.

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

I wish to set an onClickListener on items of a ListView but I see two methods `setOnItemClickListener` and `setOnItemSelectedListener` . I didint find any justified explanation for these two in official docs. Which one to use for what purpose?

To select an item, the user will have to click the item then what is the use of different methods?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is like

the item is clicked (single selection)  vs the item is selected (used in multiple selection)

Comment: +1 for the differentiation between single selection and multiple selection. Worth noting for anyone else landing here from a search that single selection can be set by settings listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)

Answer (score 4):

Difference between these to methods is presented in their description:

```
has been selected vs has been clicked
```

Actually, the difference is just the same as one between *selected* and *clicked* in Android terms.
Select it's more like highlight, please refer to more detailed explanation about *selected* state [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) (under android:state_selected).
Click is the same as *pressed* in android terms and described under the same link but under android:state_pressed.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily true. You can have a ListView that will be navigable with the keyboard or accelerometer. Also clicking an item doesn't need to mean selecting it - maybe after selecting something once you want to block selection until some other event happens.

For all purposes if you want to react to a selection of an item use the `setOnItemSelectedListener` but if you want to react to the user clicking on them go with `setOnItemClickListener`.

Answer (score 0):

I think `OnItemSelectedListener` is invoked when an item in the list is selected using navigation keys of a keypad or by using tackball.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but it is my opinion.Might be wrong.
setOnItemClickListener:Register a callback to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has been clicked.It always return true.

setOnItemSelectedListener:Register a callback to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has been clicked.it return true and also false. 
If not selected any item then it will show nothing is selected.It is just force to user that select an option.Select an item and go next just kind of that.
But when user forgot to select an item then if will remembered also user that he did not select any option.