# Can't select ListView items

Tags: java, android

I have a ListView that uses a custom adapter. Each element in the ListView contains a RadioButton and a TextView.

Here is my adapter, it takes an ArrayList of Employees (An object that currently only contains a name):

```
public class EmployeeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Employee> {

    private ArrayList<Employee> listEmployees;

    // Give the adapter the context and layout we are operating it, as well as a list of employees to put in the list.
    public EmployeeAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Employee> listEmployees) {  
            super(context, layout, listEmployees);  
            this.listEmployees = listEmployees;
            }  

    // We override the basic getView function since our list is custom.
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
        View v = convertView;


        // If there is nothing left to put in the view, inflate the view in the rowemployee layout.
        if (v == null){
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.rowemployees, null);
        }

        Employee i = listEmployees.get(position);

        // Check if there's still an employee in the list.
        if (i != null){
            TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_employeename);
            name.setText(i.getName());

        }

        // Alternate row colors.
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
              v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            } else {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e5fff4"));
            }



        return v;

    }
}
```

Here is the listview declaration in my XML layout:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/employees_list"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                    android:paddingRight="1dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/borderlist"
                    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" 
                    android:listSelector="#48ad82"
                    android:layout_below="@id/employees_header">
                </ListView>
```

And here is the layout of every item of the ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/row_employee"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="13dp"
    android:paddingBottom="13dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_employee"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_employeename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/radio_employee"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:focusable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I input a bunch of Employee objects into an ArrayList, which I push to the adapter, and then I set a setOnItemClickListener on the list. The listener contains this code:

```
OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener_employee
    = new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(view.isSelected()) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    };
```

view.isSelected() always returns false. Why? I've been trying to figure out how to select an element on a list containing something else than just a TextView for a couple of hours, and the SDK documentation isn't very helpful, this is getting old.

When I press on the list's items, it seems like the TextView or the RadioButton get pressed instead. Shouldn't focusable="false" prevent this ( [Android custom ListView unable to click on items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121192/android-custom-listview-unable-to-click-on-items?rq=1) )?

Comment: Looks like view shouldn't be selected in Your case - here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293615/setonitemclicklistener-vs-setonitemselectedlistener-in-listview/12293697#12293697 some explanation about selected state specific. Also, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:choiceMode is not about selection, but choice.

Comment: Then how do I check if the view (Or list item in this case) has been chosen? android:choiceMode="singleChoice" is already set on my ListView. Or rather, how do I pick up the item that's been chosen? I haven't been using Android for very long and I get rather confused at times.

Comment: Seems You can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemPosition%28%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the item chosen, add the following method to your adapter (untested code):

```
public Employee getItemAt(int position){
    return listEmployees.get(position);
}
```

Then in your handler, pass the position to the new adapter method above

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    Employee e = adapter.getItemAt(position); //or whatever your adapter instance is named
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Since the view is just for displaying data, you really don't care about the view itself (unless you want to remove it, hilight it, etc).

Comment: Well yea, I want to press the radiobutton and highlight the view.

Comment: then in the onItemClick method, add the code to do so: view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.hilightColor); and the code to change the radio button state. You should also look into the [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) class to not have to do this in code.

Comment: The issue I have with StateListDrawable is that I have no idea what state I'm supposed to use for the chosen item. I have tried state_pressed and state_selected and neither work.