# Android - Adding a button causes a custom listener to not work

Tags: android

I added a button on list_item.xml and my setOnDataSelectionListener(OnDataSelectionListener listener) doesn't seem to work. All I did was add a button to the LinearLayout, and the listener stopped working. Is there something that needs to be done after adding the button?

list_item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clickable="true"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dataItem01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ff888888"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dataItem02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textColor="#ccf88107"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingRight="4dp"
                android:clickable="true"

                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dataItem03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#191775"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
statusList = (StatusListView) findViewById(R.id.statusList);
statusAdapter = new StatusListAdapter(this, mHandler);
statusList.setAdapter(statusAdapter);
statusList.setOnDataSelectionListener(new OnDataSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Status curItem = (Status) statusAdapter.getItem(position);
            String curText = curItem.getText();
            Log.d(TAG, "display curtext"); // no log displayed
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), curText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // obviously no toast message 
        }
    });

LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout list_item = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
Button deleteBtn = (Button)list_item.findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);
deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "delete button clicked");

            statusList.setOnDataSelectionListener(new OnDataSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "delete button clicked inside onDataselected");

                    DeleteStatusThread thread = new MainActivity.DeleteStatusThread(id);
                    thread.start();
                }
            });
```

StatusListView:

```
public class StatusListView extends ListView {

private OnDataSelectionListener selectionListener;

public StatusListView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    init();
}

public StatusListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    init();
}

public void init() {
    setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickAdapter());
}


class OnItemClickAdapter implements OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (selectionListener == null) {
            return;
        }
        selectionListener.onDataSelected(parent, view, position, id);
    }
}

public void setOnDataSelectionListener(OnDataSelectionListener listener) {
    selectionListener = listener;
}

public void setAdapter(BaseAdapter adapter) {
    super.setAdapter(adapter);
}


public BaseAdapter getAdapter() {
    return (BaseAdapter) super.getAdapter();
}
```

}

Comment: where have you set the button in your activity ?

Comment: in MainActivity. I updated code in MainActivity.class

Comment: Use setOnItemSelectedListener for list View also please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293615/setonitemclicklistener-vs-setonitemselectedlistener-in-listview)

Comment: M.Moman, thanks for your post. I'm using a custom listener called setOnDataSelectionListener.

Comment: show complete code of your main activity

Answer (score 0):

If any row item of list contains focusable or clickable view then OnItemClickListener won't work.

The row item must have a param like **android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:gravity="center_vertical" >

// your other widgets here

</LinearLayout>
```

set any focusable or clickable view in this item with:

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. I added those lines to list_item.xml, but the issue is still alive :(

Answer (score 0):

If you added the button to list_item.xml you wouldn't initialize the button there because MainActivity as I assume it is not MainActivity's layout file. Instead you should inflate the list_item.xml layout in your MainActivity with a LayoutInflater. Also, I don't see where you initialize your button or declare it in MainActivity but don't forget when doing so it is

```
Button buttonExample = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_id_from_xml);
```

Then you can use an onClickListener

```
buttonExample.setOnClickListener(this);
```

I usually make one onClickListener method with a switch case that changes what happens based on the id of whichever button was clicked that called onClickListener. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your post Josh. In fact I did inflate the list_item.xml in MainActivity. Could you verify it if I did it correctly?

Comment: Yes, sorry I started typing my response before you added more of your code to the question. You should initialize and declare your LayoutInflater object like this

`LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`

Comment: here is an exmaple from my own code
`@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        if(adsRemoved){
            menu.findItem(R.id.btn_ads).setEnabled(false);
        }
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;

    }`

this makes an actionbar based off of an xml resource I named menu.xml in my menu directory.

Also, I see you created your LayoutInflater object but I don't see where you called the inflate object after creating it such as my above example: `inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);`

Comment: Also, I see you left your button's id as 'button' in your xml file. you need to make that id the same as what you call it in your activity at `R.id.delButton` which would look something like 'android:@+id/delButton' 
and your don't need the xml name before `findViewByID(R.id.delButton);` in your activity. It would simply be `Button del = (Button)findViewById(R.id.delButton);`
 `del.setOnClickListener(this);`
then in your onClickListener method you can add a switch case to do what you want depending on which button is being clicked determined from the buttons id.

Answer (score 0):

set `android:focusable="false"` to your button in the  list_item.xml.

Comment: It doesn't seem to fix the issue. The list items are still not clickable